# TestFairy "No permissions" using REST

Tags: macos, rest, curl, testfairy

I am trying to use the REST API for TestFairy as described [here](http://docs.testfairy.com/API/Rest_API.html) http://docs.testfairy.com/API/Rest_API.html. However, no matter which API I am trying to call I always get:

```json
{
   "status":"fail",
   "code":106,
   "message":"No permissions"
}
```

I am using OSX and curl, like so:

```
curl -u "EMAIL:API_KEY" "https://app.testfairy.com/api/1/projects"
```

Where of course **EMAIL** and **API_KEY** is replaced with the respected values.

What am I doing wrong?

Using the password for my TestFairy account instead of the **API_KEY** always results in "User not found".

On another note; the account is using the free plan of TestFairy. Does that make a difference in the availability of the REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, raw API access is a paid-plan feature available only for Startup and Enterprise packages. That's why you're getting the "no permissions" error. You should email TestFairy's support for more info.

Comment: That sure does explains it. Thanks a lot for info :)